# Should questions about specific tools be considered "off topic" for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

After having a question specific to the LLVM compiler "clang" closed as being "off-topic", I double checked the help/faq and did not find any guidelines that would suggest that the question was out of bounds.

The original close nominator suggested that because the answer might be related to a design decision, for that reason, it was off-topic.

The post in question is here:

> [Is there a known set of `c++11` features in clang enabled by default not requiring `-std=c++11`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513867/why-does-clang-expose-some-c11-features-by-default-and-require-std-c11?noredirect=1#comment39789588_24513867)

Comment: Questions about a specific tool aren't off-topic.  Questions why a the developers of a specific tool made a specific decision usually are off-topic.

Comment: I see, but I'm not asking what was going on in their head. I want to know if there is a conceptual reason for doing so, as the results of such a decision have a profound effect on portability of code, and which features are "safe" to use.

Comment: For some people the word "Why" is a trigger word for voting to close.  That might have contributed to why it was closed

Comment: @Catskul I was speaking in a very general sense (responding to your title).  I'm not qualified to judge whether your question should be open or closed, but one of the issues might be how you phrased the question.  "Why" is tough question to do right because it is very opened ended and invites speculation and opinions (even when you don't want them), especially when you combine it with "Anyone have clue".  You might try to rework the question to try to avoid those type of open ended trigger phrases and focus on your specific concerns.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you might be thinking about the following comment.

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about design decisions made by the creators of clang, which can likely only be answered by them, and are very likely quite opinion based.

This comment looks like it came from a custom close reason.

It appears as though that close voter(and maybe other close voters) believed that your question was problematic because it **"can likely only be answered by them,(the creators of clang)"**, and because it is also **likely quite opinion based.**

The problem isn't that the question is about Clang.  If you had asked a non-duplicate question about **how to use** clang, your question probably wouldn't be closed.

Comment: I don't agree with the assertion that it's likely only answerable by the creators nor that it's likely to be opinion based. There may be a well known conceptual or standards based reason for why certain features would be exposed. IMO the problem with closing such a question is that it's not clear whether the answer falls into the "arbitrary design decision" category until someone who knows comes along and answers.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you an idea of what we consider on-topic for various tools questions:

```
Candidate Question                                    Is it on-topic?
-----------------                                     ---------------
Usage of Visual Studio                                Yes.
Installation of Visual Studio                         Yes.
Configuration of Visual Studio                        Yes.
Design of Visual Studio                               Maybe.  Writing a plugin?
Usage of SQL Server                                   Yes.
Configuration of SQL Server                           Begrudgingly.
Installation of SQL Server                            Not really.
Design of SQL Server                                  Probably not.
```

Is the design of Clang on topic?  It depends.  Can you tie it to a specific problem you are having with Clang that relates directly to an application you are writing?

Comment: What's the difference between "maybe" and "probably not" here and what do you mean by "the design of SQL Server"? It's certainly possible to elucidate why certain things are the way they are and the impact that has on coding practices. On the installation point I'm mostly agreed but it's possible to set up minimal installs to test things rather than a full commercial database. Would this be on-topic? The commercial installation would be on DBA and (probably) Server Fault but the home test kit?

Comment: Stack Overflow likes specificity.  Note the additional words after "maybe."

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I were to analogize with SQL server as the topic, my question might be "Why does SQL server use a lock during operation X" which would be a conceptual "design" question of the same sort but, IMO, on topic. No?

Comment: @Catskul: That could potentially be tied to a programming problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so can mine. I tend to intentionally avoid describing the details of the related programming problem because then it requires a ridiculously long post about tangentially related issues.

Comment: @Catskul: Curiosity questions about tool internals without a practical concern tend to be too broad.